# How to speed up MYISAM table for too many reads?

Tags: mysql, performance

ive got **problems with my DB**. When i have lot of people on my site, it is going really slow. I have checked **MTOP** tool and I have lot of slow queries from one table called "users", it is **myISAM** table from which there are too many reads. I am using mysql + nginx + php-fpm and i am trying to fix this problem for a month now and i didnt figure it out, please help.

Do you know how i can optimize table, or so to perform READ faster?

Here is simple output from MTOP (see, queries are simple ie. select Nick from users where id=123456... simple, indexed with primary, but too many select)

> 1673185    blindr       localhost     blindr         0  Query select Nick from users WHERE Id='737436'
>
> 1677220    blindr       localhost     blindr         0  Query select Fotka_ok from users WHERE Id='5732083'
>
> 1677986    blindr       localhost     blindr         0  Query select P_pohlavie from users WHERE Id='6416249'

there are too many reads from this table users and lot of time they are occuring in MTOP slow queries which i guess problems...

Do you have any suggestions how to speedup MYISAM reads?

Comment: What software are you running? was it developed by you? Maybe you can somehow cache the user and reduce the calls to the db

Comment: hello, thank you for the reply, yes it is my website in PHP... i am using query cache and memcached... but i still get lot of READ queries from that table (which is fine) because it is programmed like that, i need those queries to be like that, but how can i optimize that table users for too many READS whithout touching my software?

Comment: It seems that your form retrieves each column using individual queries instead of just one query ==> ,use ONE query `SELECT nick, fotka, pohlavie FROM users` instead of three separate queries: `select Nick from users ..`, `select Fotka_ok from users` , `select P_pohlavie from users `

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE users;`

Comment: How big is the table?

Comment: @kordirko yes it is, is it possible to optimize it for this or that is the problem?

Comment: @RickJames table has only 18 000 rows... i am attaching requested show create table, see it here (http://blindr.eu/info.txt)...

Comment: KEY `Online` (`Online`) is unnecessary because of KEY `users1` (`Online`,`Id`,`Rande`).  You have `INT` for what looks like true/false flags; they could be `TINYINT`, shrinking the space from 4 bytes to 1.  @kordirko point about having 1 select instead of 3 is very important -- assuming it cuts back the number of queries significantly.  That will "speedup MYISAM reads", which is what you asked for.

Comment: thank you very mutch for help :)